# Generate small images or components in a grid space

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I was wondering how you would be able to generate multiple images that fit along a grid space or have equally distance between each other.

I wanted to do like an interactive item editor and everytime you pressed "generate image" button, it will generate images on a certain area and will be alligned like they are in a grid space.

I made a little example program and pretend that the buttons in the mini square are suppost to be images.

Everytime I click Generate Image, it will generate images just like that, but maybe a bit more spaced out

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [TilePane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/TilePane.html).

There is an example of laying out images in a tiled area in the TilePane javadoc:

```
TilePane tile = new TilePane();
tile.setHgap(8);
tile.setPrefColumns(4);
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    tile.getChildren().add(new ImageView(...));
}
```